# Respecting the "\n" newlines (and special characters) returned from API response in the HTML display

Tags: javascript, html, sinatra, newline

I am accessing data via an API that returns strings in the following format:

> Hello this is some text.\n\nHere's some more that includes a phrase in
>   \"quote marks\".\n\nAnd another thing:\n\n* Bullet point.\n*
>   Bullet point.\n* Bullet point.\n* Fin.

This is a sinatra app, and in my view I simply access the variable and display this with something like:

```
<%= thing.description %>
```

When it is rendered, none of the newlines are actually respected. It's all shown as a single line. I'm not sure of the right approach to fix that. Is there a way to replace the `\n`s with `<br>` tags? Or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enclose the string in a `<pre>` block (usually has the additional effect of using a monospaced font), or you can enclose it in a block of your choice and style it with `white-space: pre;`.

Comment: I'd recommend `white-space: pre-wrap;`, but that depends on the use case.

Comment: ah, i wouldn't want the styling to change to monospace. can you describe how to use `white-space: pre;` or `write-space:pre-wrap;`? are those attributes on the `pre` html tag?

Comment: No, they're CSS styles and can be applied as such. E.g. `<div style="white-space:pre-wrap">`

Comment: ah, of course. and that will also keep my styling in place such that the monospace font won't happen? will give it a shot in just a bit! :)